# Create a new SQL Server which has a period in the name

Tags: sql-server-2008

I apologize if this is a repost but I didn't find exactly what I needed.

I'm running SQL Server 2008 Developer edition on my machine. I've tried dropping my old server (which was the name of my machine) and adding my new one such that `select @@servername` returns the new name 'test.k5'. However, I can't connect to this inside the management studio. Is there something I'm missing?

Or is there a much better approach to doing this?

Comment: This belongs on Database Administrators SE. (http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your question correctly.  Are you saying you changed the network name of your machine that is running SQL Server?  If so, this should be giving you the *wrong* name:

```
exec sp_helpserver
```

or

```
select @@servername
```

Here's what you need to do to fix this, **if this is the problem**:

```
exec sp_dropserver 'YourOldMachineName'
go
exec sp_addserver 'YourNEWServerName', 'local'
go
```

If this is not what you mean, then please let me know and we'll go from there.